# How can I implement custom maps with provinces in Android?

Tags: java, android

Ok, so I have this map and I have various sliders on the right. After changing slider values and pressing 'Execute' button, some provinces in the map below should change colour. 
[image]

However, I don't know how to implement the map below. I have used 33 png drawable for each province. I have set them all to have a same big rectangle dimension so that they'd align themselves. 
**I am getting an 'Out of memory on byte allocation' error.**
I assume this is because of all the large drawables I have. 
I'm new to android and I want to ask, is there a way to implement this without the error?
Also the map should always be displayed on the left side of the screen so the images always have to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a SVG and changing the colors programmatically.

Graphics are hard to scale and are heavy space users, scalable graphics are slim, look great everywhere (device size and dpi) and easy to manage (single file instead of 33).